# Is there any way in R through which first column can be made as a header

Tags: r

I want to make the first column of the table data as a header in R.

```
X            sub1 sub2 sub3........
carnitine     0    1    1
betaine       0    0    0
acetate       1    1    1
iodine        0    1    0
fluconazole   0    0    1
.
.
.
```

This is the function that is used to read the text file.

```
InitFeatures<-function(namefeatures){
  p0<-paste0("./", namefeatures)
  features <- as.matrix(utils::read.delim(p0, sep="\t"))
  return(features)
}
```

So when i run the command `features<-InitFeatures("abc.txt")`, only row header is created. I want that the column X should also be made as a header.

Comment: If it is a table, then use `dimnames(tbl)[[1]]`

Comment: Is there a reason to convert to matrix? You could use `readr::read_table` to avoid row names altogether, or `tibble::rownames_to_column` if you had a data frame with row names.

Comment: Try if `colnames(features) <- features$X` works, assuming the `nrow(features)` = `ncol(features)`

Answer (score 1):

One option can be:

## To get the first column as header

Note that if you want your first column as header, the length of columns and rows must be the same. Otherwise, you'll have more names than columns and vice versa.

```
#Get names
names(df) <- df[,1]
#Remove first column
df <- df[,-1]

#Sample data
df <- read.table(text = "X            sub1 sub2 sub3
carnitine     0    1    1
betaine       0    0    0
acetate       1    1    1", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

## First column as a header when the columns length and row are not the same

```
#Repeat names according to the number of columns 
names(df) <- rep(df[,1], dim(df)[2])[1:dim(df)[2]]

#Sample data
require(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 3, ncol = 10)) %>% 
  mutate(X1 = letters[1:3])
```

## To get the first row as a header

```
#Get names from first row
names(df) <- paste(df[1,])
#delete first row
df <- df[-1,]
```

Result:

```
             X sub1 sub2 sub3
2   carnitine    0    1    1
3     betaine    0    0    0
4     acetate    1    1    1
5      iodine    0    1    0
6 fluconazole    0    0    1
```

Sample data:

```
df <- read.table(text = "X            sub1 sub2 sub3
carnitine     0    1    1
betaine       0    0    0
acetate       1    1    1
iodine        0    1    0
fluconazole   0    0    1", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: What is the use of `paste` when renaming the `df` ?

Comment: True, I don't need it for the first part. Thank you :)

Comment: @DJV the length of columns and rows in my data are not same.

Comment: Would you like the names to repeat/stop by the length of the columns?

Comment: my data has 1369 columns and 650 rows.